# Texture paint effects entire solid

Tags: texture-painting

I'm a beginner in Blender, so forgive me if this description is simplistic or the solution is obvious.

I am trying to paint on a black image texture on the solid. The texture looks like this.
[image]

But when I make even a small stroke on the top, the whole thing turns gray with a couple of black spots at the bottom.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I've asked more experienced people, and they don't know what's going on, and I can't find anything online. What's going on here?

And I guess here's some more screenshots to see if those help.

[image]

This is the UV map.
[image]

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the reason for the Polish mask to be truthful to you. You probably have overlapping geometry with different materials. But I can't see your objects to help you. What I would do is remove the Polish Mask image and rewire the principled bsdf to your material output since you have everything there. Then since I understand you want to paint the Base Color image I would pick the base color image and paint on it. I wouldn't change anything else besides looking for duplicate objects of the anvil.

Something is clearly wrong with the material because you can see this grey anvil has a normal map. Since you haven't connected the normal map image to your output it's impossible the material you are showing to be the one we look on the top image. Because the Polish image you have connected is a simple image with no detail, no normal or anything. The anvil should look simple low poly.

My guess is this. 2 same anvils overlapping. One has the material with the polish mask you show us and one has the principled BSDF with all the images connected to the Principled BSDF like the third image and then to the output.

Next time include the whole screen please. Let's not play find the problem with as less clues there can be.